# Flutter how to check if there is a device connected to my device via bluetooth

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, bluetooth

I'm writing a flutter app which uses bluetooth Connectivity. I want to know if my device is connected to another device via bluetooth. I want to ask if there is something like Internet connectivity with bluetooth if there isn't I want to know if there is a method to replace it.

My app has as role to open bluetooth is it's off I did it and then if the device bluetooth state is connected or not to another device.

```
void checkconnectivity() async{
//check bluetooth connectivity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package [bluetooth](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth)

Example:

```dart
/// Create a connection to the device
var deviceConnection = flutterBlue.connect(device).listen((s) {
    if(s == BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
        // device is connected, do something
    }
});

/// Disconnect from device
deviceConnection.cancel();
```